# Wave Characteristic diagram question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Say $F(x)=v(x)=0$ when $|x| \geq a$ whilst $F(x)=h(x)$ and $v(x)=c \ h'(x)$, both when $|x|<a$.  As we know, the wave equation in D'Alembert's form is:
$$ 
y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[F(x-ct)+F(x+ct)\right] + \frac{1}{2 c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} v(s) \,ds.
$$
I calculated that $y(a,t)=\frac{h(a)}{2}$ in $t \in (0, \frac{2a}{c})$ but I'm curious how to calculate $y(a,t)$ for $t > \frac{2a}{c}$?

I think the answer is $0$ because the wave moves outwards from the center at speed $c$ so eventually it will pass the point $a$.  However, if time is on the $y$ axis, does this mean it stays at position $a$ and just increases on $y$?

Can someone please clarify my intuition of the characteristic diagram involving the time parameter?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with piecewise defined initial conditions, it helps to draw the regions of dependency of each piece. To do this, draw the line $x=x_0\pm ct$ for each point  $x_0$ separating  two pieces:

[image: spacetime]

I  put big fat $0$s in the regions which do not depend on $[-a,a]$. The rest of space-time is divided into three parts.

In part (iii), 
$$y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[h(x+ct) + h(x-ct)\right] + \frac{1}{2 c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} ch' (s) \,ds =  h(x+ct)  $$
This describes the  wave moving to the left keeping its profile.

In Part (i), 
$$y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[h(x+ct)\right] + \frac{1}{2 c} \int_{-a}^{x+ct} ch' (s) \,ds =  h(x+ct) - \frac12 h(-a) $$
This is also the  wave moving to the left in its original form, but with the added shock from the discontinuity at $-a$ (which doesn't exist if $h(-a)=0$).

Part (ii) is similar and is left as an exercise. It will have $h(x-ct)$, plus the shock from the discontinuity at $a$.